# SwiftUI how to align the view‘s leading to the most super view’s leading?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widget

I’m new to SwiftUI and I’m making a widget. The default code included a text view which is both x-centered and y-centered in the super view(which I don’t know if there’s the same concept in SwiftUI).
This is my code:

```
struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text(Date(), style: .time)
                .padding(.leading)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to align the view’s leading to the super view’s leading instead of positioning the text in the center. So I tried to add a padding to the text’s leading, strangely, it seems that the text view is not a direct subview of the superview, it is positioned in a invisible centered view instead, since I end up with having a text view that slightly deviate the center, looks like this:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I tried the position method and it was the only one worked, not perfectly though, since it is based on the center point.

I’m looking for a better solution.

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Playground that gives an example of a view that looks like your picture:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ViewWithText : View {
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Here")
            .background(Color.yellow)
        }
        .frame(width: 320, height: 480, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}

let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ViewWithText())
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = hostingController
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple padding and background you can see why it does not work for you as you want.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
    Text(Date(), style: .time)
        .padding(.leading)
        .background(.yellow)
}
.padding()
.background(Color.gray)
```

The base size of the `VStack` is the same as the size of it's children. Solution would be to increase the size of the `VStack` or the size of the `Text`

In widget I suggest to set the parent `(V)Stack`'s size (`maxWidth`) as big as it can get (`.infinity`) :

```
VStack(alignment: .leading){
    Text(Date(), style: .time)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
.padding()
```

Btw setting `padding(.leading)` is causing the "text view that slightly deviate the center" as this added a base padding to the left size of the Text. It just increases the width of the text, but still not fully to the available width.